# How to set a test for multiple fetches with Promise.all using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs

I'm using jest for my tests. I'm using react and redux and I have this action:

```
function getData(id, notify) {
 return (dispatch, ...) => {
   dispatch(anotherFunction());
   Promise.all(['resource1', 'resource2', 'resource3'])
   .then(([response1,response2,response3]) => {
        // ... handle responses
    })
   .catch(error => { dispatch(handleError(error)); }
 };
}
```

I've been looking for into the jest documentation how to set a test for this action, but I was unable to find a way. I tried myself something like this:

```
it('test description', (done) => {
  const expectedActions = [{type: {...}, payload: {...}},{type: {...}, payload: {...}},...];
  fetchMock.get('resource1', ...);
  fetchMock.get('resource2', ...);
  fetchMock.get('resource3', ...);
  // ... then the rest of the test calls
});
```

Unsuccessfully. So how should I proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use `Promise.all` you could do the following

```
test('Testing Stuff', async (done) => {

  const expectedActions = [{ foo: {...}, bar: {...} }, { foo: {...}, bar: {...} }];

  // we pass the index to this function 
  const asyncCall = async (index) => {
    // check some stuff
    expect(somestuff).toBe(someOtherStuff);
    // await the actual stuff
    const response = await doStuff( expectedActions[index] );
    // check the result of our stuff
    expect(response).toBe(awesome);
    return response;
  };

  // we put all the asyncCalls we want into Promise.all 
  const responses = await Promise.all([
    asyncCall(0),
    asyncCall(1),
    ...,
    asyncCall(n),
  ]);

  // this is redundant in this case, but wth
  expect(responses).toEqual(awesome);

  done();

});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can tell Jest to wait for the promise to resolve by returning the promise in the callback. See this section [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#promises) for more info.

```js
it('should fetch some food', () => {
  const fetchItem1 = () => fetchData1().then(data => {
    expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
  })
  const fetchItem2 = () => fetchData2().then(data => {
    expect(data).toBe('boiled egg');
  })
  const fetchItem3 = () => fetchData3().then(data => {
    expect(data).toBe('fried salad');
  })

  return Promise.all([fetchItem1(), fetchItem2(), fetchItem3()])
    .then(() => runOtherTests());
});
```

Comment: You are my hero. I tried lot of threads and await Promise.all surrounded by try and catch worked. Thanks for the hint.